# Selecting distinct JOIN table data in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

We have a mechanism that lets a user view available Accelerators (attachments) for a given AsapStructure row (Node). They can bind multiple Accelerators to that individual Node.

I have two tables that are a many to many relationship (Has and belongs to Many)

`AsapStructure` hasAndBelongsToMany `Accelerators`

These two tables are joined via `accelerators_nodes`.

The scaled down schema is as follows:

**AsapStructure:**

- id
- title
- progress_status
- created
- modified

**Accelerators:**

- id
- title
- progress_status
- created
- modified

**accelerators_nodes (Join Table)**

- id
- node_id
- accelerator_id
- progress_status
- created
- modified

What I am trying to do, is select all 'Accelerators' that have a progress_status of 5, and the associated Node (AsapStructure - IF it exists. If it is NULL, i want to return the accelerator anyways, it just means that there is no relationship YET)

Each table has a progress_status field, this is just information about that particular row. In the case of the AsapStructure/Accelerator tables, this just indicates whether or not that document is approved.

For the join table, progress_status indicates whether or not that relationship has been approved.

The SQL I have generated gets close, but it selects duplicate records, it is as follows:

```
SELECT 

    AsapStructure.id,
    AsapAccelerator.id,
    AsapAccelerator.foreign_id,
    AsapAccelerator.title,
    AcceleratorsNode.progress_status,
    AsapAccelerator.filename,
    AsapAccelerator.filesize,
    AsapAccelerator.language,
    AsapAccelerator.doctype,
    AsapAccelerator.progress_status,
    AsapAccelerator.modified
FROM
    accelerators AS AsapAccelerator
        left JOIN
    accelerators_nodes AS AcceleratorsNode ON (AcceleratorsNode.accelerator_id = AsapAccelerator.id)
        left JOIN
    asap_structure AS AsapStructure ON (AcceleratorsNode.node_id = AsapStructure.id)
WHERE
    AsapAccelerator.progress_status = 5
ORDER BY AsapStructure.id ASC, AsapAccelerator.title ASC
LIMIT 50
```

**Sample Output**

```
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
    | id   | id   | foreign_id | title                           | progress_status | filename                                                          | filesize | language | doctype       | progress_status | modified            |
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
    | NULL | 1963 |       1211 | Value Delivery Scorecard        |            NULL | 484_Value_Delivery_Status_Project_Scorecard_Template_MS_Draft.doc |   113152 | English  | Template Form |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:53 |
    |    1 | 1686 |        933 | Going Live Check Sample Report  |               4 | 459_SAP_GoingLive_Check_Analysis_Session_Sample_Report.doc        |   779264 | English  | Sample        |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:21 |
    |    1 | 1792 |       1100 | Preliminary Cutover Strategy    |               4 | 471_Preliminary_Cutover_Strategy.ppt                              |  1070080 | English  | Presentation  |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:33 |
    |  933 | 1686 |        933 | Going Live Check Sample Report  |               5 | 459_SAP_GoingLive_Check_Analysis_Session_Sample_Report.doc        |   779264 | English  | Sample        |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:21 |
    | 1100 | 1792 |       1100 | Preliminary Cutover Strategy    |               5 | 471_Preliminary_Cutover_Strategy.ppt                              |  1070080 | English  | Presentation  |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:33 |
    | 1151 | 1894 |       1151 | Cutover Communications          |               5 | 56_Cutover_Communications.xls                                     |   120320 | English  | Template Form |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:45 |
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, the SECOND `id` column contains the ID of the Accelerator. The first `id` column is the ID of the AsapStructure row. You can see that there are duplicate rows in the second `id` field, 1686 and 1792 respectively.

The first row, you can see that the first `id` field is `NULL`, this just means that there is not a relationship between an AsapStructure row and that Accelerator.

**My Goal**

I want to select ALL available Accelerators, regardless of whether or not it is attached to an AsapStructure row. If it IS attached to an AsapStructure row - I ONLY want to return it if it matches XX (the Node ID of the document they are viewing and want to add attachments [Accelerators] to), otherwise return NULL.

The reason behind this, is we are displaying a paginated list, and the items in that list will display the status of the relationship, IF it exists. If it does not exist, we just give them an option to take action on that item.

**Desired Result**

Here is the (desired) output of the SQL query, as you can see it is selecting unique records, and also note the `id`'s of the first `id` field.

```
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
    | id   | id   | foreign_id | title                           | progress_status | filename                                                          | filesize | language | doctype       | progress_status | modified            |
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
    | NULL | 1963 |       1211 | Value Delivery Scorecard        |            NULL | 484_Value_Delivery_Status_Project_Scorecard_Template_MS_Draft.doc |   113152 | English  | Template Form |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:53 |
    |    1 | 1686 |        933 | Going Live Check Sample Report  |               4 | 459_SAP_GoingLive_Check_Analysis_Session_Sample_Report.doc        |   779264 | English  | Sample        |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:21 |
    |    1 | 1792 |       1100 | Preliminary Cutover Strategy    |               4 | 471_Preliminary_Cutover_Strategy.ppt                              |  1070080 | English  | Presentation  |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:33 |
    | NULL | 1894 |       1151 | Cutover Communications          |               5 | 56_Cutover_Communications.xls                                     |   120320 | English  | Template Form |               5 | 2012-03-05 23:56:45 |
    +------+------+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

This way, when we iterate over the data, we can easily determine:

- If it is bound to a document
- IF it is bound to a document, then we can determine the status of that relationship.

If there is an easier way to do this, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try grouping by accelerator id?

```
SELECT 

    AsapStructure.id,
    AsapAccelerator.id,
    AsapAccelerator.foreign_id,
    AsapAccelerator.title,
    AcceleratorsNode.progress_status,
    AsapAccelerator.filename,
    AsapAccelerator.filesize,
    AsapAccelerator.language,
    AsapAccelerator.doctype,
    AsapAccelerator.progress_status,
    AsapAccelerator.modified
FROM
    accelerators AS AsapAccelerator
        left JOIN
    accelerators_nodes AS AcceleratorsNode ON (AcceleratorsNode.accelerator_id = AsapAccelerator.id)
        left JOIN
    asap_structure AS AsapStructure ON (AcceleratorsNode.node_id = AsapStructure.id)
WHERE
    AsapAccelerator.progress_status = 5
GROUP BY AsapAccelerator.id
ORDER BY AsapStructure.id ASC, AsapAccelerator.title ASC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Yes I did, and the problem with that was if there were multiple ID's associated with that accelerator id, the one it selected was unpredictable.